# Denying authorization at moment on ASP Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented a refresh token mechanism on a Web Api solution, so I reduced the livetime of the access tokens, but I have to wait for the access token to expire to request another token with the refresh token. What I currently need is to deny access at the current moment (for example the user is blocked), inmediatily denying access in the next API calls. I currently implemented an action filter, the only thing is that it is being called on every request so it is an additional call to the database, I wondered if there is any other method for denying access to an access token

Comment: when token is blacklisted add it to a cache for the remainder of the life of the token and check for it there.

Comment: @Nkosi how could I implement something like that? Do you have any link or resource I could check?

Comment: In the same filter you mentioned. instead of going back to the db check the cache to see if token is blacklisted. When you blacklist a token you add it to the same cache that the filter checks.

Comment: That means that I should store the access tokens besides the refresh tokens?

Comment: I don't understand the last comment. I though the desire was to block access token. how does refresh token come into play.

Comment: The refresh token is the one that I save on the database not the access tokens, so I understand is that I should change my authentication process to store/block the access tokens directly

Comment: well you only need to store the black listed ones temporarily